# How to do a Spatial Join after opening a GDB file with Fiona?

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, software-recommendations, spatial-join, fiona

After I successfully open up an ESRI GDB file/folder with Fiona, what open-source Python package should I use to do a spatial join?

I was told Shapely is not the appropriate package for this.

I am completely new to GIS.

Comment: [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066) with Fiona and Shapely

Comment: As long as you are specifying that you do not want to use Shapely I think this question is unique from the one linked by gene. However, why were you told Shapely was not appropriate for this application?

Comment: I thought using Shapely was the most straightfoward way to approach doing a spatial join.  I was told in this thread:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193210/how-to-parse-through-a-esri-gdb-file-folder-after-opened-with-fiona that:  "Shapely is a computational geometry library: buffers, intersections, &c. It doesn't do spatial joins but can be used to help your own join implementations."

Answer (score 3):

Look first at [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066)

The results of Fiona are Python dictionaries (GeoJSON format)

```
import fiona
layer = fiona.open("test_regex.shp")
# first feature
first = layer.next()
print first
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(203371.23902535878, 89863.381050732), (203353.45178501407, 89474.60279748365), (203217.99038220354, 89246.7813473023), (203147.8656364849, 89284.24525254924), (203144.05848558623, 89691.61039870887), (203371.23902535878, 89863.381050732)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1), (u'dip', 30), (u'dip_dir', 150)])
```

Now if you want to use  topological predicates (contents(), intersect() and others) the easier is to use Shapely (or equivalents, look at [Python Geo_interface applications](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications))

```
from shapely.geometry import polygon, shape
geom = shape(first['geometry'])
print geom
POLYGON ((203371.2390253588 89863.381050732, 203353.4517850141 89474.60279748365, 203217.9903822035 89246.7813473023, 203147.8656364849 89284.24525254924, 203144.0584855862 89691.61039870887, 203371.2390253588 89863.381050732))
```

Now you can use `geom.intersection(another_geom)`, `geom.contains(another_geom)` and others therefore Shapely is an appropriate package for this (try to do the same with the original data)

You can also use [Spatial Indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) ([Fastest way to join many points to many polygons in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172197/2581)) and other solutions as [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/), based on Fiona, Shapely and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) ([More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc (2)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165413/2581))

#### New

With a GDB file

```
gdb = fiona.open("test.gdb")
gdb.driver
u'FileGDB'
gdb.schema
{'geometry': 'MultiLineString', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 'int')])}
gdb.crs
{'init': u'epsg:31370'}
# first feature
gdb.next()
{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiLineString', 'coordinates':   [[(-1.2543001174926758, 0.22390007972717285), (-1.05430006980896, 0.6630001068115234), (-0.6935000419616699, 0.6284000873565674), (-0.30660009384155273, 0.7262001037597656), (0.3064999580383301, 0.8891000747680664)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', None)])}
# all the features
for feature in gdb:
   print feature
{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiLineString', 'coordinates': [[(-1.2543001174926758, 0.22390007972717285), (-1.05430006980896, 0.6630001068115234), (-0.6935000419616699, 0.6284000873565674), (-0.30660009384155273, 0.7262001037597656), (0.3064999580383301, 0.8891000747680664)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', None)])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiLineString', 'coordinates': [[(-0.3847999572753906, 0.14569997787475586), (-0.16669988632202148, -0.12890005111694336), (0.09349989891052246, -0.3803999423980713)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '2', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', None)])}
 ....
```

Comment: Thank you.  I just tried your first example, but my toy app crashes when I try the layer.next() command.  I know I've opened up the GDB file "correctly" as Fiona does not provide an exception and I can see that there is metadata tags.

Comment: You have a problem because the result of fiona.open is a Python iterator with `next() ` and if it crashes you have not opened up the GDB file "correctly"

Comment: The Fiona open command doesn't cause an exception and I was told that I could do something like this the code below to verify successfully opening a GDB file

with fiona.open(gdb_path) as src:
    print(src.meta)

Comment: Perhaps but if `next() `does not work you cannot access the features, so..

Comment: Is there any other way for me to establish / verify that I did open the GDB? I know I can print layer the first time it's assigned when Fiona opens up the GDB file.

Comment: look at New in my answer

Comment: Gene,  I seem to still be crashing when using the next function, but I do get similar outputs for the prior functions in your new GDB example.  Just so I have an understanding, does calling schema and crs step you through the GDB structure to put you in a position to start using next to call the next feature?

Comment: schema, crs or driver are only shapefile or GDB metadata, nothing to do with the records of the shapefile (next feature, next , ...)

Comment: Ah, so your use of them (schema, crs, etc.) was merely to illustrate where in the GDB I am looking?

Comment: So digging around some more, it appears the next() command is causing Fiona's "collection.py" file (line 318) to crash... this is where it says "return next(self.iterator)"  Did I set something up bad?  Or is something wrong with my GDB file?

Comment: Gene, so I think I figured out what my problem is... I think the GDB file I'm using got corrupted migrating it from Windows to Linux.  I'll have to request someone to physically copy it since the archive manager I used may be suspect in causing the problem I have.  Although the next command would crash the program, the for loop just simply ran and exited with no errors.  I believe I may have an empty GDB with metatags.

Comment: Gene, Just for closure's sake I got around my script crashing whenever doing a layer.next() call by enumerating a fiona.listlayers() call instead.  For whatever reason, next() is hostile towards the ESRI-generated GDBs I've used.